# MySQL - Calculate the difference between rows

Tags: php, mysql, rows, difference

So I'm working with MySQL and PHP. Having some trouble trying to get a query that calculates the difference between consecutive rows.

What I need is to get the difference between each row for: `data_views`, `data_sub` & `data_videos` for each channel URL.

Much appreciated if anyone can help :)

Here's my table structure:

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Have you tried anything or just thought asking help for your assignment ?

Comment: So you want to calculate the difference between the ids 1-3, 3-4, 4-5 and so on?

Comment: Can you just put these values in arrays and then perform the subtraction on the array values?

Comment: @Qirel It's for each channel_url (so... WHERE channel_url = '...')

Comment: @user1270513 How would I go about doing that?

Comment: select (data_views-data_sub-data_videos) AS result from `your table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..if you don't want ordering just remove ORDER BY A.channel_url clause..

```
SELECT 
  A.*,
  A.data_views - IFNULL(B.data_views, A.data_views) AS data_views_diff,
  A.data_subs - IFNULL(B.data_subs, A.data_subs) AS data_subs_diff,
  A.data_videos - IFNULL(B.data_videos, A.data_videos) AS data_videos_diff 
FROM
  my_table A 
  LEFT JOIN my_table B 
    ON B.id = 
    (SELECT 
      MIN(id) 
    FROM
      my_table C 
    WHERE C.id > A.id 
      AND C.id != A.id 
      AND C.channel_url = A.channel_url) 
ORDER BY A.channel_url;
```

Check [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/687cdc/1)